# Best Data Visualization Technique for real time data obtained in tabular form?

Tags: user-expectation, design, info-visualisation, ux-field

I need some guidance with the following problem-
I have a table of huge data which looks somewhat like the diagram below:

[image]

1. There are 6 servers. Each server contains 3 folders. (The number of servers may later increase)
2. The folders contain the number of files present in the folder and the values may even range to billions.
3. The values are in real time.

What would be the best way to represent all this data in such a way that it's easily understandable by the user? I only have limited knowledge of data visualization techniques and am not sure which way of representing it would be the best way.

Cheers!

Comment: Hello> I understood the tabular presentation at a glance. The vertical presentation made me take time to build a table :D Ergo I contend that the data best be represented in 3D. [Think VR] Sorry me grapher is not on this machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's already explaining itself but you may ask for further questions.

> PS: Please don't care if the percentages and the file sizes don't corelate with the presented charts/graphs.

The location, position, and outlook of the texts can be modified according to your project needs/custimizations (e.g. The percentage display of the servers can be represented better vertically --I suppose).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I had initially thought of going with multiline bar charts as well but was was unsure if it was the best method for real time data given that real time data is generally represented by line charts. However, this helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome and I'm happy as well if I could help besides waiting you to accept it as an answer if it's a solution to your question.

Comment: This is a good solution, but what happens if folders are 0 or very small?

Comment: The texts representing the folder names and their sizes can be moved alongside the bar charts instead of staying on them. Does it help to imagine @Devin?

Comment: yes of course, and I figured that would be the answer, but wanted to make sure